# While loop - Scala

Tags: scala, while-loop

1) Is it possible to iterate through an Array using while loop in Scala?

2) How to find the numbers that are greater than 50 using reduce loop?

```
val reduce_left_list=List(12,34,54,50,82,34,78,90,3,45,43,1,2343,234)

val greatest_num=reduce_left_list.reduceLeft((x:Int)=> { for(line <- reduce_left_list) line > 50)
```

Comment: Just so that you know, the barrage of downvotes are probably due to the fact that you gave no indication of having tried anything, other than "do my homework while I go have lunch" type request dumped on others.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is it possible to iterate through an Array using while loop in Scala?

That depends on your definition of "iterate through an array". You can certainly do the same thing that you would do in C, for example, that is taking an integer, increasing it by 1 in every iteration of the loop, stopping when it is equal to the size of the array, and use this integer as an index into the array:

```
val anArray = Array('A, 'B, 'C, 'D)

var i = 0
val s = anArray.size

while (i < s) {
  println(anArray(i))
  i += 1
}
// 'A
// 'B
// 'C
// 'D
```

But I wouldn't call this "iterating through an array". You are iterating through integers, not the array.

And besides, why would you want to do that, if you can just [tell the array to iterate itself](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#foreach(f:A=>Unit):Unit)?

```
anArray foreach println
// 'A
// 'B
// 'C
// 'D
```

If you absolutely insist on juggling indices yourself (but again, why would you want to), there are much better ways available than using a `while` loop. You could, for example, iterate over a [`Range`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html):

```
(0 until s) foreach (i ⇒ println(anArray(i)))
```

Or written using a `for` comprehension:

```
for (i ← 0 until s) println(anArray(i))
```

Loops are *never* idiomatic in Scala. While Scala *does* allow side-effects, it is generally idiomatic to avoid them and strive for referential transparency. Albert Einstein is quoted as saying "Insanity is doing the same thing and expecting a different result", but that's *exactly* what we expect a loop to do: the loop executes the same code over and over, but we expect it to do a different thing every time (or at least once, namely, stop the loop). According to Einstein, loops are insane, and who are we to defy Einstein?

Seriously, though: loops *cannot* work without side-effects, but the Scala community tries to avoid side-effects, so the Scala community tries to avoid loops.

> 2) How to find the numbers that are greater than 50 using reduce loop?

There is no such thing as a "reduce loop" in Scala. I assume, you mean the [`reduce` method](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#reduce[A1>:A](op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1).

The answer is: No. The types don't line up. `reduce` returns a value of the same type as the element type of the collection, but you want to return a collection of elements.

You *can*, however, use a fold, more precisely, a [right fold](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#:[B](z:B)(op:(A,B)=>B):B):

```
(reduce_left_list :\ List.empty[Int])((el, acc) => if (el > 50) el :: acc else acc)
//=> List(54, 82, 78, 90, 2343, 234)
```

You can also use a [left fold](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html#/:[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B) if you reverse the result afterwards:

```
(List.empty[Int] /: reduce_left_list)((acc, el) => if (el > 50) el :: acc else acc) reverse
//=> List(54, 82, 78, 90, 2343, 234)
```

If you try appending the element to the result instead, your runtime will be quadratic instead of linear:

```
(List.empty[Int] /: reduce_left_list)((acc, el) => if (el > 50) acc :+ el else acc)
//=> List(54, 82, 78, 90, 2343, 234)
```

However, saying that "you can do this using a left/right fold" is tautological: left/right fold is *universal*, which means that *anything* you can do with a collection, can be done with a left/right fold. Which means that using a left/right fold is not very intention-revealing: since a left/right fold can do anything, seeing a left/right fold in the code doesn't tell the reader anything about what's going on.

So, whenever possible, you should use a more specialized operation with a more intention-revealing name. In this particular case, you want to filter out some particular elements that satisfy a predicate. And the Scala collections API actually has a method that filters, and it is called (surprise!) [`filter`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html#filter(pred:A=>Boolean):Repr):

```
reduce_left_list filter (_ > 50)
//=> List(54, 82, 78, 90, 2343, 234)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`withFilter`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html#withFilter(p:A=>Boolean):scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic[A,Repr]) instead:

```
reduce_left_list withFilter (_ > 50)
```

The difference is that `filter` returns a *new list*, whereas `withFilter` returns an instance of [`FilterMonadic`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/FilterMonadic.html), which is a *view* of the existing list that only includes the elements that satisfy the predicate.

Comment: I agree that one should not "iterate over an array" in general. But as you ask why someone would : I always do it in performance critical code (numeric computation). All functional methods, like .map and even for in scala, are implicitly using a function call to run the loop content code. This has a cost which, for really critical performance code only, should be avoided. Also, it is very easy to create many useless intermediary collections using functional methods (but avoidable though).

Basically in those cases, I code c-style with mutable collection and while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try [filter](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#filter):

```
List(12,34,54,50,82,34,78,90,3,45,43,1,2343,234).filter(_ > 50)
```